# Bash Alias for Firejail Sandbox

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I’m wanting to make a bash alias to be able to run applications sandboxed in Firejail that will make a temporary folder that will disappear on reboot. Is this right?

alias sandbox ()
{
firejail --seccomp --nonewprivs --private --private-dev --private-tmp --net=none --x11  "$1"}

Not sure if this is how to use the variable ($1). I want to be able to use, “sandbox Firefox” or other apps and it run in firejail.

Comment: You're almost writing a function ([3.3 Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions)) -- just remove the `alias` keyword.  Contrast with [6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

Comment: So just drop the word “alias” and put the function in my .bashrc? Did I use the variable ($1) correctly?

Comment: Yes to both questions.